# Implement boolean search in apache solr search

Tags: search

I am working on Apache solr search. I want to implement boolean search in apache solr search.

On  google i found following [article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1662653/how-to-do-boolean-search-in-apache-solr) and many more articles.

I have also seen the [hook_apachesolr_query_alter](http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions!apachesolr!apachesolr.api.php/function/hook_apachesolr_query_alter/7) but i have no idea how to implement the apache solr alter function.

If any one have prior information how to implement it, please guide me to achieve it

Answer (score 0):

Here is a basic example of adding an extra parameter to the search query using the hook_apachesolr_query_alter()

```
/**
 * Implements hook_altersolr_apachesolr_query_alter().
 */
function mymodule_altersolr_apachesolr_query_alter($query) {
  $query->addParam('fq', 'my_field:(value)');
}
```

Check this page for more possibilities on altering the search query: http://drupalcontrib.org/api/drupal/contributions%21apachesolr%21apachesolr.interface.inc/interface/DrupalSolrQueryInterface/7